# Google Adsense ads disappear from my webpage

Tags: ads, adsense

I have a google adsense account and inserted a ad into my webpage.
After I add the code provided from google adsense, several minutes later, I can see the add is showing on my webpage, but about a quarter later, the ad disappeared and only leave an empty, white blank, area there.

And it was also a strange thing, The preview area of google adsense page below text ad style label is not working. no matter which style I choose, the preview area show a blank area, and I found the response of request, requested by google adsense script, just return an empty html segment like this :

`<html><body style="background-color:transparent"></body></html>`

Anyone had got same question ? Help me please, It had already token me a whole day for this.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a new ad, it will take a while before it will serve ads.

Besides that, if you reload your page to often while testing for the ad to appear, adsense will not serve new ads. Your ip will not get new ads for a while. Just wait a little and they will appear again.

You can check your page through a proxy to see if ads are displayed through other IP's. Or ask a friend to check your page of use another internet connection.