# Adsense banners showing transparent background

Tags: adsense

Believe me that I've asked this in Adsense forums (Spanish AND English), and also checked the following resources and questions:

[1](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/adsense/X9FGWr4ls3U) - [2](http://forums.serif.com/showthread.php?t=99179) - [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33743171/google-adsense-ads-disappear-from-my-webpage) - [4](https://productforums.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!msg/adsense/5tksWBlBu3k/Wd-zZilKEwAJ)

I have an AdSense account that actually works with AdMob. We see successfully ads on Android, but I can't see them for web. We can create in AdSense new ads without a problem and we let pass even more than 2 months to ads to set themselves up, but nothing changed.

Still, the answer I get from ads is a 200 status with the following HTML content:

`<html><body style="background-color:transparent"></body></html>`

Giving bounty since none has been able to resolve it, nor Google Forums or Stackoverflow!

---

EDIT

We've checked with a brand new account and it works!! Our original account is not banned though and it's serving ads for AdMob, but the problem comes with AdSense (for web)!

Comment: Would You mind accepting the answer if I answered Your question? :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had almost the same problem once. With the settings I made Google was not able to get advertisement for my page. See the answer:

> https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/113262?ctx=tltp&hl=en

The solution (for me) was to add a new `unit` and a completely new `channel` as well. If You check the `If no ads available` option You can choose from 3 options:

- Collapse the ad unit, otherwise show blank space (default)
- Collapse the ad unit, otherwise show colour
- Show other URL

If the problem persists you should send a feedback message including the URL, the exact description of the problem. This is maybe an internal problem in Googles algorithm (as if it is not able to find ads for you).

**Important:** Have you checked from different browsers, other machines and Google accounts? The algorithm behind the whole AdSense motor is relying on those information heavily. (It means that if You do not see ads on your site, it still could show some to others.)

***Edit:*** If You tried to use a newly created unit and it did not work, I suspect a google bug and I am mostly out of ideas. In my case this solved the problem, but if You are unlucky with it You really should use an other account if possible.

Comment: It even ignores what to do in case there's no ad. I'm trying with an account that we know it works, and it does, but there's no way to make this work. I don't know where to send the feedback, I've tried spanish and english forums and none answers.

Comment: There is a send feedback button on the leftt on the admin panel. Based on the source you provided, google was not able to give you ads. Did You check it on other machines as suggested?

Comment: Yes I did actually.
We're different testers with different computers and browsers

Comment: And, regarding the comments, I've sent comments to around 15 days ago. This is really useless when you can't solve it anyway and you can't contact directly Google.

Comment: If You tried even to use a newly created unit and it did not work, I suspect a google bug.. and I am mostly out of ideas. In my case this solved the problem, but if You are unlucky with it You really should use an other account if possible.